# How accurate is a ripple counter (using D flip-flop) in measuring the frequency of a signal?

Tags: frequency, measurement, counter, frequency-measurement, ripple-counter

I have two oscillating signals S1 and S2 whose periods are always different by a very tiny amount (~10-50ps). Can I use a D-flip-flop ripple-counter to measure S1 and S2 individually, and then subtract the 2 measurements to find out what is the delay difference between S1 and S2? If yes, how accurate would the computed delay difference be compared to the actual delay difference?

Comment: You're probably better to add a diagram or more details of what you're trying to achieve. If the signals start off in phase maybe an XOR gate would be better, are you trying to implement some sort of TDOA (time difference of arrival) system?

Comment: What's the frequency of the signal?

Comment: What is the waveform, what is the frequency range and what the output will be (a pulse, a DC voltage, a frequency?)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a phase-frequency detector (PFD). These circuits are quite often used in phase-locked-loops (PLLs) for producing a "clean" reference signal that is locked-on to a fairly noisy (or modulated) input signal. The heart of the PFD can be shown in the logic diagram on the picture below (extract taken from [here](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC100EP140-D.PDF)): -

[image]

The two outputs labelled "U" and "D" stand for up and down respectively and these two outputs can be combined with equal value resistors to produce an output voltage that represents the frequency/phase difference between two signals.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_detector) also provides some information about this type of circuit.

[This Maxim article](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/files/maxim/0002/appno090.htm) also shows how one can be implemented using D type flip-flops: -

[image]

> How accurate would the computed delay difference be compared to the
>   actual delay difference?

This is a difficult question to answer directly but I will say that PFD circuits, when used as the heart of a PLL, can achieve sub milli-hertz accuracy on locking an oscillator to an unknown input frequency of hundreds if not thousands of mega-hertz. Your two signals will begin in phase at some point and, due to the frequency difference between the two signals will drift to being completely out of phase - this will result in a cyclical output of the PFD which should be easily seen using an oscilloscope. Given that you then know how often the phases align, it is a trivial matter to compute what the average phase (or time delay) difference is per cycle.

Comment: A PFD would seem to only be workable as an analog device; as a digital pulse it would generate "runt" pulses which would cause all sorts of metastability problems.  Depending upon the input frequencies, if one wants digital measurements, it would seem easier to put both inputs through ripple counters to scale them by some amount (e.g. 65,536:1) and then time them; a 10ps difference multiplied by 65,536 would be 655.36ns, which should be large enough to measure using conventional techniques.

Comment: @supercat The output will be an analogue signal in make-up but the fact that the two signals will move in and out of complete phase at a particular rate will give all the OP needs to calculate the average phase drift per cycle between the two frequencies.

Comment: @supercat, normally the output of this kind of PFD is put through a low-pass filter to generate a "dc" analog signal proportional to the duty-cycle of the PFD output, which in turn is proportional to the delay between the input signals.

Comment: @ThePhoton: I guess I'm not quite clear whether the fact that the periods are different implies that the frequencies are different, or that there's cycle-to-cycle variation in period but the frequencies are the same, or what.

Comment: @supercat, I agree, the question is not clear on that. If the frequencies are different, you could probably solve this with just an AND gate instead of a PFD.

Comment: @ThePhoton: An "and" gate would output lots of runt pulses.  It might be better to feed both signals into a 2-bit counter, and feed the MSB of one counter into a 74HC595 which is clocked by the other pulse and hits the register strobe every 4 pulses.  The downstream 4 bits of the shifter should hold a pattern of highs and lows which should shift by one place every cycle one signal gains or loses relative to the other.  Everything but one of the counters would be clocked by the same input, and four shifter bits should be adequate to synchronize the input from the other clock domain.

Comment: The outputs from the 595 would only change meaningfully at a rate proportional to the difference in input frequencies, and could be sampled/synchronized at any desired rate faster than that (e.g. if the frequencies will be within 1000Hz, one may sample at any desired rate, uniform or not, provided the time between samples never exceeds 1ms).

Comment: Guys, this type of PFD isn't just a figment of Maxim's imagination - Analog Devices use exactly the same circuit (or so they say) in devices such as the ADF4156 - check out page 10 of http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/ADF4156.pdf. I've also used the same configuration in an EPLD.

Comment: @supercat, just like with the PFD, you'd run the output of the AND gate through a LPF to convert those "runt pulses" into a dc level.

Comment: @ThePhoton: One could get a level which would rise and fall at a rate proportional to the frequency difference, but if one wanted to count the beats one would have to add hysteresis to ensure that one didn't falsely count ripple; if one wants a beat signal one can "count", staying in the digital domain would seem easier.

Answer (score 0):

(sorry, too long for a comment) 
Your text contains some misunderstandings, or maybe bad wordings.

- What is a frequency difference of 10-50ps?
- A ripple counter does not measure, it counts. To use it to measure a frequency you must reset it, let it run for some time, stop it, and then the outputs indicate the frequency.
- First you state that your oscillators differ in frequency, later you talk about a delay difference. What is it?